# Python: Why does reversed(a)==reversed(a) returns False where a is an array?

Tags: python

This is the code

```
>>> a=[1,3,2]
>>> a
[1, 3, 2]
>>> a= 3,1,2
>>> a
(3, 1, 2)
>>> sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(a)==sorted(a)
True
>>> reversed(a)==reversed(a)
False
```

Further

```
>>> b= reversed(a)
>>> sorted(b)==sorted(b)
False
>>> sorted(b)==sorted(b)
True
```

I saw this in a youtube video and can't figure out what's happening.

and that guy also showed

```
>>> sorted(b)
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `reversed()` returns an iterator while `sorted()` returns a new list.

The lists that you get back from `sorted()` are equal lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3]

>>> sorted(a) == sorted(a)  # The equality here is checking that the lists contain the same objects in the same order
True
>>> sorted(a)[0] is sorted(a)[0]
True  
>>> sorted(a) is sorted(a)  # However, they are not the same lists, modifying one will not modify the other
False
```

The iterators that you get back from `reversed()` are going to be different each time you call it:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> reversed(a)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x01C2A9D0>
>>> reversed(a)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x01AB4EF0>
```

Consuming one of these iterators twice will cause it to yield an empty list the second time as you see in your last example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = reversed(a)
>>> list(b)
[3, 2, 1]
>>> list(b)
[]
>>>
```

These empty lists that we get back out of the iterator will explain the 2nd exmaple:

```
>>> b= reversed(a)

    # The first sorted(b) is the real sorted list, the second one is an empty list because the iterator has been consumed
>>> sorted(b)==sorted(b) 
False

    # Now both of our sorted(b) are just empty lists, since the iterator has been consumed
>>> sorted(b)==sorted(b)
True
```

Comment: You are just 30 seconds fast ;)  Anyway, deleted it.

Comment: "The lists that you get back from `sorted()` are the same object every time you call it" - not true.

Comment: @user2357112 Ty, corrected they are not the same object but they are equal lists

Comment: The use of the words "same" or "different" is still pretty handwavy. It doesn't explain in what sense the objects are the same or different.

Answer (score 3):

`sorted` returns a new, sorted list. `reversed` returns a reverse iterator. Comparing two lists with the same elements for equality yields true. Comparing two different iterators doesn't.

If you were to compare lists constructed with the reverse iterator, you'd get `True`:

```
>>> reversed(a) == reversed(a)
False
>>> list(reversed(a)) == list(reversed(a))
True
```